# Proper way to check type when object might be an object() instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I'm looking for the proper way to check a type of object that might be an instance of object() now i'm doing this:

```
def _default_json_encoder(obj):
    """ Default encoder, encountered must have to_dict
    method to be serialized.  """
    if hasattr(obj, "to_dict"):
        return obj.to_dict()
    else:
        # object() is used in the base code to be evaluated as True
        if type(obj) == type(object()):
            return {}
        raise TypeError(
            'Object of type %s with value of '
            '%s is not JSON serializable'
            % (type(obj), repr(obj))
        )
```

but

```
if type(obj) == type(object()):
    return {}
```

is not recommended, unfortunately

```
if isinstance(obj, object):
    return {}
```

won't work because all object will be evaluated as True.

So `type(obj) == type(object())` is the only way ?

Comment: Why do you think you need to test for `object` instances? **Everything** in Python 3 is an instance of (a subclass of) `object`. Do you have actual `object()` instances in your data, and if you do, why?

Comment: And the usual way to test for a class is to use `isinstance(obj, class)`, but again, for the `object` class, that's everything. You can use `type(obj) is object` to disallow any subclasses. I'm puzzled as to why you'd need this however. Why not just use `True` or some dedicated class instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, because in some case the I have made affectation with object() then i need to repr this (instance attribute) as dict.

Comment: But why? What is the actual problem you tried to solve by using `object()`?

Comment: I answered in my previous comment. the need to repr an instance attribute as {}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have instances of `object()` in your data structure, then you'd use:

```
type(obj) is object
```

to test for direct instances (classes are typically singletons).

However, I'd rethink my data structure, and either use another primitive value (like `True`), a dedicated singleton, or a dedicated class.

A dedicated singleton could be:

```
sentinel = object()
```

then test for that sentinel:

```
if obj is sentinel:
    return {}
```

Comment: As usual nice response, Thanks !